# Customize R base plot fonts (macOS)

Tags: r, macos, quartz-graphics

I have followed [this blog](https://www.r-bloggers.com/changing-the-font-of-r-base-graphic-plots/) to customize base R plot font on macOS (using `quartzFonts()` in `.Rprofile`), with success to a certain degree. My problem with this approach is, defining a new font family has to be put in a function such as `.define.fonts()` and upon enter a R session (I use Rstudio), I have to manually invoke the following from the console:

```
.define.fonts()
par(family='new_font_family')
```

I can't simply define new font family by calling `quartzFonts()` in `.Rprofile`. My guess is that this command is not available until graphic device has been initialized. Is there anyway to automate this?